# Centering 2 divs seperatly inside a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution for this problem:
I have a container div which gets its height / width from a div/img inside it with dynamic height. 
inside that container I want to add another square div 72x72px which will be centered both horizontally and vertically.
[image: example]

css solution is preferred

thanks for the help

current html:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-like"></div>
    <img src="dsada"/>
</div>
```

current less:

```
.post:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
  background: #808080; width: 5px;
}

    .post{
  background:  @white;
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
img{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
}
 .post-like
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

    }
```

Comment: post your current css

Comment: added less and html, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty old trick which work for this case

http://jsfiddle.net/9x1zLhz8/

#### html

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x500" alt="" />
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.container {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -36px 0 0 -36px;
}
```

Comment: wich is exactly what i talk about, but parent needs to be position else you may have funny result.... add this info to your answer, not only to the fiddle

Comment: that's what I was looking for, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display:table` to shrink div on content(image) and then the oldish relatif/absolute way of centering things to stick your box over the image..

```css
.ib {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
}
.top {
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);

}
.h72.w72.center {
  height:72px;
  width:72px;  
  margin:-36px;
}
picture,legend {
  box-shadow:0 0 5px, inset 0 0 2px;
  text-align:center;
}
picture img {
  display:block;
}
/* extra if understood by browser*/
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<picture class="ib">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400"/>
  <legend class="h72 w72 center top flex">
    center top layer
  </legend>
</picture>
```

[Codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pvdpQQ)

Comment: @web-tiki , thnks for this info !! i'll keep this slink in my fvorites :), see you there once in a while.